# How can I subset by date, using a wild card?

Tags: r, date, subset

I have a data frame :

```
$Date, $name, $value
1949-05-01, Hurricane, 5
1950-02-01, Hurricane, 6
1950-03-01,
1950-04-01,
1950-05-01,
1951-02-01,
1951-03-01,
1951-04-01,
```

These dates go all the way to 2015, with measurements for months 02, 03,04 and 05. I am trying to create a dataframe, or subset of this data that only has the rows that are for April (04). I have tried some code such as

```
aprilSWE <- hurricane.df[grep("^04", hurricane.df$Date),]
```

But I am not sure if I am using the `^` correctly. As the month "04" is in the middle of the date string, how can I use wildcards to select any row that has a "04" in the month as the date?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you are not using `^` correctly. The `^` anchor asserts that the regular expression engine's current position in the string is the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use string processing for this. Use the `Date` class:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Date, name, value
    1949-05-01, Hurricane, 5
    1950-02-01, Hurricane, 6
    1950-03-01, Hurricane, 7
    1950-04-01, Hurricane, 8
    1950-05-01, Hurricane, 9
    1951-02-01, Hurricane, 10
    1951-03-01, Hurricane, 11
    1951-04-01, Hurricane, 12", header = TRUE, sep =",")

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
DF[months(DF$Date) == "April",]
#        Date       name value
#4 1950-04-01  Hurricane     8
#8 1951-04-01  Hurricane    12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hurricane.df[grep('^\\d{4}-04', hurricane.df$Date),]
```

Or convert to 'Date' class and use `format`

```
hurricane.df[format(as.Date(hurricane.df$Date), '%b'=='Apr',]
```